# ERROR while connecting to SSL elasticsearch on aws glue spark-scala

Tags: apache-spark, ssl, aws-glue

I am running a spark scala job on aws glue where I am trying to connect to secured SSL enabled elasticsearch on AWS glue. I get error

```
 Logging - Unable to execute HTTP request: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1207)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1153)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5140)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getBucketRegionViaHeadRequest(AmazonS3Client.java:5932)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.fetchRegionFromCache(AmazonS3Client.java:5905)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5124)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5086)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1338)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.call.GetObjectMetadataCall.perform(GetObjectMetadataCall.java:26)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.call.GetObjectMetadataCall.perform(GetObjectMetadataCall.java:12)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.executor.GlobalS3Executor.execute(GlobalS3Executor.java:114)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.invoke(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:191)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.invoke(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:186)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:96)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AbstractAmazonS3Lite.getObjectMetadata(AbstractAmazonS3Lite.java:43)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.getFileMetadataFromCacheOrS3(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:431)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadata(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:200)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3NativeFileSystem.java:493)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkDest(FileUtil.java:511)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:387)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(FileSystem.java:2424)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(FileSystem.java:2390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(FileSystem.java:2353)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(EmrFileSystem.java:568)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.LogPusher.upload(LogPusher.scala:57)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.LogPusher.run(LogPusher.scala:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:331)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:274)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:269)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:377)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:422)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:182)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:152)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1401)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1309)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:142)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy61.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExe
```

I am providing truststore using system properties

```
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", filePath)
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", pass)
```

I dont face an issue while I run on local machine, but face issue when running on AWS glue 3.0.
I tried multiple option using extra-files in glue params and setting --conf in glue but nothing works